# C# ElasticSearch get external objects by nested list element property comparison

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Let's suppose we have the following 2 objects (**Please ignore the strange situation, as it is used only to model the real issue**):

```
public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSalary { get; set; }
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; } = new List<Position>();
}

public class Position
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentPosition { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int? MonthsWorked { get; set; }
    public bool HasAverageLimitStatistic { get; set; } = false;
    public int AverageMonthLimit { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

How do I write a query in **NEST (C#)** to find all **people** who work (or worked) on **positions** which are coming close to `AverageMonthLimit` in a timespan of a year, (positions without `AverageMonthLimit` are ignored); in case `MonthsWorked` is provided than compare it to `AverageMonthLimit`, otherwise take today's date and compare it to `ExpirationDate`.

PS: If the position has the statistic, then minimal `AverageMonthLimit` is of **36** months. People might work on several jobs.

**NOTE:** **MSSQL** script would probably look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person p
JOIN Position pos
    ON pos.PersonId = p.Id
WHERE
    pos.HasAverageLimitStatistic = 1
        AND pos.AverageMonthLimit > pos.MonthsWorked
        AND pos.AverageMonthLimit - 12 < pos.MonthsWorked
    OR pos.HasAverageLimitStatistic = 0
        AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), pos.ExpirationDate) > 0
        AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, GETDATE(), pos.ExpirationDate) < 12
```

**UPDATE**

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I presume the question boils down to the following, where query is unknown:

```
var response = _elasticClient.Search<Person>(s => s.Query(q =>
    .DateRange(x => x
    .Field(p => p.Employees
        .First(pos => pos.HasAverageLimitStatistic == null)
        .ExpirationDate)
    .GreaterThan(DateTime.Now)
    .LessThan(DateTime.Now.AddYear(1))) 
    // upper code finds customers who don't have statistic
|| q.Nested(x => x
    .Path(p => p.Positions)
    .Query(qq => qq.Script.Inline(" ?????? "))));
```

Comment: Are `Position` a `nested` type on `Person`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you've meant, but `List<Position>` is nested.

Comment: I mean, is `List<Position>` mapped as a `nested` type? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Let's consider each case separately (even though nested does seem better, a failsafe would be good)

Comment: they would need to be mapped as `nested` types here. Have you given it a crack? If so, could you show what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks, made `Position` nested... See the update, I have added the code I though of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying against `nested` types, you need to use [`nested` queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html), which will take care of querying against the internal documents that `nested` types are modelled with.

Here's what your SQL query would look like in Elasticsearch

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.Positions)
            .Query(nq => (+nq
                .Term(f => f.Positions.First().HasAverageLimitStatistic, true) && +nq
                .Script(sq => sq
                    .Inline("doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value != 0 && doc['positions.averageMonthLimit'].value > doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value")
                ) && +nq
                .Script(sq => sq
                    .Inline("doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value != 0 && (doc['positions.averageMonthLimit'].value - 12) < doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value")
                )) || (+nq 
                .Term(f => f.Positions.First().HasAverageLimitStatistic, false) && +nq
                .DateRange(d => d
                    .Field(f => f.Positions.First().ExpirationDate)
                    .GreaterThan(DateTime.Now.Date)
                    .LessThan(DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(1))
                ))
            )
        )
    )
);
```

There's a fair bit going here, so I'll break it down

1. Inside the top level query, [a `nested` query will be performed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nested-query-usage.html). Since all predicates (i.e. WHERE clauses) are based on properties of `nested` types, these queries will all be inside of the `nested` query.
2. Specify the `Path` to the `nested` type on the top level type
3. Inside the `nested` query's query, 3 queries are `&&`ed together within parentheses for the first set of predicates where `HasAverageLimitStatistic` is `true` and 3 queries are `&&`ed together in parentheses for the second set of predicates where `HasAverageLimitStatistic` is `false`.
4. Since all queries test whether some condition is true or not, we can forgo calculating a score for them by making them `filter` clauses in a `bool` query. NEST has handy shorthand for `bool` query `filter` clauses in the form of the [unary `+` operator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#unary-plus-operator). [Similarly, there are overloaded operators combining queries with `&&` and `||`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html)
5. Because you want to compare two properties on an indexed document, you need to use a `script` query to do this. [In Elasticsearch 5.x, the default language for this is Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html).

The query DSL JSON for the above query is

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "positions.hasAverageLimitStatistic": {
                        "value": true
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "script": {
                      "script": {
                        "inline": "doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value != 0 && doc['positions.averageMonthLimit'].value > doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "script": {
                      "script": {
                        "inline": "doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value != 0 && (doc['positions.averageMonthLimit'].value - 12) < doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "positions.hasAverageLimitStatistic": {
                        "value": false
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "positions.expirationDate": {
                        "gt": "2017-06-03T00:00:00-07:00",
                        "lt": "2018-06-03T00:00:00-07:00"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "path": "positions"
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, here's a complete example to demonstrate

```
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .InferMappingFor<Person>(m => m
            .IndexName("people")
        )
        .PrettyJson()
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        .OnRequestCompleted(response =>
            {
                // log out the request
                if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri} \n" +
                        $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{response.HttpMethod} {response.Uri}");
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                // log out the response
                if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Status: {response.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                             $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
                }
            });

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    if (client.IndexExists("people").Exists)
    {
        client.DeleteIndex("people");
    }

    client.CreateIndex("people", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Person>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Nested<Position>(n => n
                        .Name(nn => nn.Positions)
                        .AutoMap()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.IndexMany(new[] {
        new Person
        {
            FullName = "Person 1",
            TotalSalary = 100000,
            Positions = new List<Position>
            {
                new Position
                {
                    Name = "Janitor",
                    AverageMonthLimit = 5,
                    MonthsWorked = 3,
                    HasAverageLimitStatistic = true
                }
            }
        },
        new Person
        {
            FullName = "Person 2",
            TotalSalary = 150000,
            Positions = new List<Position>
            {
                new Position
                {
                    Name = "Coach",
                    AverageMonthLimit = 5,
                    HasAverageLimitStatistic = true
                }
            }
        },
        new Person
        {
            FullName = "Person 3",
            TotalSalary = 200000,
            Positions = new List<Position>
            {
                new Position
                {
                    Name = "Teacher",
                    HasAverageLimitStatistic = false,
                    ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6)
                }
            }
        },              
        new Person
        {
            FullName = "Person 4",
            TotalSalary = 250000,
            Positions = new List<Position>
            {
                new Position
                {
                    Name = "Head",
                    HasAverageLimitStatistic = false,
                    ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(2)
                }
            }
        }
    });


    client.Refresh(IndexName.From<Person>());

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Nested(n => n
                .Path(p => p.Positions)
                .Query(nq => (+nq
                    .Term(f => f.Positions.First().HasAverageLimitStatistic, true) && +nq
                    .Script(sq => sq
                        .Inline("doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value != 0 && doc['positions.averageMonthLimit'].value > doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value")
                    ) && +nq
                    .Script(sq => sq
                        .Inline("doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value != 0 && (doc['positions.averageMonthLimit'].value - 12) < doc['positions.monthsWorked'].value")
                    )) || (+nq 
                    .Term(f => f.Positions.First().HasAverageLimitStatistic, false) && +nq
                    .DateRange(d => d
                        .Field(f => f.Positions.First().ExpirationDate)
                        .GreaterThan(DateTime.Now.Date)
                        .LessThan(DateTime.Now.Date.AddYears(1))
                    ))
                )
            )
        )
    );

}

public class Person
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSalary { get; set; }
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; } = new List<Position>();
}

public class Position
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsCurrentPosition { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public int? MonthsWorked { get; set; }
    public bool HasAverageLimitStatistic { get; set; } = false;
    public int AverageMonthLimit { get; set; } = 0;
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the query criteria, only Person 1 and Person 3 are returned.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time, I basically learned ElasticSearch querying by this example =)

Comment: Awesome, happy to help!